# Is accessing core data relationships in a for loop slow?

Tags: sql, objective-c, sorting, core-data

I have 2 models, one is called Books, the other is called Users. As a relationship, a User can have exactly 1 book. I want to loop over all my users who are "approved" (an attribute on User) and sort them based on an attribute stored in Books called rating. I wrote this to do so:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedApprovedUsersByBookRating
{
    NSArray *allUsersWithBooks = [User fetchFromDatabaseWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"approved == 1"] error:nil];

    NSArray *sortedUsers = [allUsersWithBooks sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(User a, User b) {
        return [a.book.rating compare:b.book.rating];
    }];

    return sortedUsers;

}
```

And this works because I have a relationship in core data on User called book and it grabs the right book, sorts it all fine and returns. However, I noticed that when I have a lot of users this is a very slow procedure. My theory is that it's because every time I access a.book or b.book, it has to fetch it from core data.

I was wondering if there's a solution to this problem that when given a set of users who's approved attribute is true, that I can return those users sorted based on their book rating, where I don't have to query for the user's book each time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `NSSortDescriptor`. So the sort will happen at the SQLite level. `NSSortDescriptor` has an initializer called `sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:selector:`. You can sort your books with the `key` attribute (it's a string). Hope this helps.